# Ember: method serializeBelongsTo variable "belongsToId" returns a promise instead of an ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, adapter, ember-cli

I've got an issue here using custom Django REST Ember-Data adapter. On the initial POST request foreign keys are fine, then after trying to HTTP PUT on the same record, belongsTo records dissapear.

```
export default DRFSerializer.extend({


    serializeBelongsTo: function(snapshot, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key;

        if (this._canSerialize(key)) {
            var fkID = snapshot.belongsTo(key, { id: true }); 
            var fkPromise = Ember.isNone(fkID) ? snapshot.record.get(key) : wrap_as_promise(fkID)

            fkPromise.then(xxx)
                ...
        }
    },
```

On the initial request the *`snapshot.belongsTo(key, { id: true })`* returns an ID but on the second request it returns a promise. But the method that calls serializeBelongsTo doesn't expect it to be a resolveable method. If I for instance resolve a foreignkey in the template/controller the snapshop.xx does return an id.

Comment: Can you share a little more about your use-case?  What are you trying to do that is causing you to bump into a foreignkey id promise?

Comment: @dustinfarris Hey dustin, I'm using the adapter you and others have written. It seems as if our API could not be compatible with JSON API standards that Ember data is looking for but i'm not in a skillset to debug it. The situation when it appear-: I make a new record everything works, i edit the newly created record, again everything works as expected.  So now i make a hard refresh. I try to edit the previusly created record and the foreignkeys are now returned as a promise. Which causes PUT hash foreign keys to => "null".  https://gist.github.com/kristjanreinhold/eb8e3b410937d067c027. Thanks